# visual studio very very slow

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, resharper

My visual studio is acting very very slow lately. I have one solution with 22 projects and it never had a problem before. I have had this size of code of few months now and it was always fast and great.

In order to debug, i have tried removing all my extensions. I have tried removing re-sharper(which I though might had been causing problems.) But it is still slow.

By build takes almost 5 minutes and running tests take almost 10-15 minutes. I have restarted my computer multiple times. Cleaned solution.

The only thing left to do is to re-install visual studio but that is not going to guarantee any kind of solution at all and before I do that, I wanted to make sure that I have done everything in my control to solve this issue.

One more thing, my visual studio profile is on network as our company's network is configured in a way that all the user's profile data resides on the network. I can not change that fact at the moment but I also wanted to know if it has any effect on the performance of visual studio build.

Is there anything that you think I should be trying?

Comment: Do you experience slowness accessing the share on the network where is your vs profile? (Writing and reading a file)

Comment: Your builds take 5 minutes? And you think that's ***slow***?!

Comment: I have the same problem even with small programs on a single processor P4.  On a QUAD processor I never see the problem.

Comment: Do you have some kind of antivirus or antimalware monitor installed lately? Or some other kind of monitor (maybe some companywide solution was automatically installed). They can cause a great slowdown.

Comment: @steve No slowness in accessing network............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's very likely that there's some kind of network access that will be slowing it down, especially as you say that the profiles are stored there.  I would suggest running [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to capture data for a few seconds and then look through the list for some network paths or run `Tools -> File Summary` or `Network Summary` to see where it is spending the time.  It could be that a server somewhere is switched off and so there are lots of network timeouts, or that there's a lot of latency or traffic on the network.

Comment: May be you are right. One thing that I have observed very particularly is that when I run test against one particular file or build one project then it is done in fractions of seconds. The problem here is not not number of tests or size of code to be built. I have observed that when I build the entire solutions, when it halts is between when it is done building one project and it picks up next project.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Turned out I had too many break points set. I deleted them all and it went back normal. So give that a try.

Comment: Same here a few years back, now I know to keep deleting them :)

Comment: Actually, I tried deleting them. No luck :((.

Comment: I just did this and it helped me!