# visual studio 2010 very slow because of periodic network access. How to solve?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My visual studio 2010 is suddenly extremely slow. After almost every mouseclick, VS hangs for about 10 seconds. I found a related question that proposed that network traffic could be the cause:

[visual studio very very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873470/visual-studio-very-very-slow)

I noticed that the problem disappeared when I plugged my laptop into my docking station at work. I then discovered that the problem also disappeared when I switched off my WLAN (there is no additional connection to the internet).

I checked with the [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and I found that visual studio was performing lot's of network requests indeed, but didn't do this when WLAN was switched off (obviously).

Here's a printscreen of the process monitor:

[image: Screenshot of ProcessMonitor]

Now, the problem's identified but I really have no clue how to solve it. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Kind regards,
Jaap Kokorian

Comment: Are you using a symbol server?

Comment: I don't know what that is, so I guess not... By the way, the first part of the adress VS is connecting to is the name of my computer: TUD251660

Comment: That is the outgoing port. The server it's connecting to is srv143.  Have a look in the Debugging options for the Symbol settings. There may be a symbol server set there.

Comment: There is one symbol server listed: "microsoft symbol server", but the checkbox in front of it is unchecked...

Comment: Ok, so it might not be symbol server then. You might get some more clues if you select a line in ProcMon and get the stack for it -- maybe it's an SCM addin, or an addin that needs to connect to a licence server.

Comment: My guess is an SCM Add-in.  Is there some way to run VS with all SCM add-ins disabled?

Comment: Sorry guys, I haven't had an opportunity yet to investigate the matter any further. I hope to get back onto it tonight.

Comment: :-S the problem seemed to have solved itself... No idea why. I hope it comes back, so we can finish this question thread. (for now I'm quite happy though) All of you, thank you very much!